# How do I show the hidden contact info?

Tags: support, status-norepro, jobs

I selected "Interested, share my contact info with this employer" and sent the response but I still can't see the hidden contact info.

Comment: If you could see the hidden info, it wouldn't be hidden info.

Comment: @ZianChoy Everything looks good when I view the page as you would see it.  You might be having some kind of caching problem.  Try reloading your browser?

Comment: @Gamecat it is not hidden but redacted, and you see a message telling you what kind of information was hidden.

Comment: I cleared my browser's cache and now I can see the info. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clear the browser cache and restart the browser.